# Multiplying two column values together with a string (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I need to multiply two columns together with a string at the beginning.

The sum works when it is formatted like this works fine;

```
SELECT LS.col1 * LS.col2 AS 'Revenue'FROM
```

However when I try this as a string it is returning an error;

```
SELECT '''£' LS.CPL * Lead_Count'' AS 'Revenue'FROM
```

Could some one help me out on this one please?

Thanks,

Connor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT CONCAT('£', LS.CPL * Lead_Count) AS `Revenue`
FROM tab
```